# Wifi Network not appearing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

We have a shared WiFi network for our hostel. After I upgraded to 14.04 that particular WiFi network is not getting listed in Ubuntu (other WiFi networks are listed and am able to connect).

However I'm able to connect to that same shared network with Windows on the same laptop. What could be the possible reason for only that WiFi network not getting listed?

I performed an `iw reg set IN` to set it to India.

The output to `lspci -nn | grep 0280` is:

```
12:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn 
Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

I performed scan for the network using `iwlist scan` . The network i want to connect to is not in the list but at the same time it is available in my mobile and other laptops near by.

Comment: What country are you in?  What channel is the router on?  What is the result of `iw reg get`

Comment: $Iw reg get gives country 00: (2402 -2472 @ 40), (3,20) | (2457 -2482 @ 40), (3,20) , PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS |(2474 -2494 @ 40), (3,20) , NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN , NO-IBSS |(5170 -5250 @ 40), (3,20) , PASSIVE-SCAN , NO-IBSS |(5735 -5835 @ 40), (3,20) , PASSIVE-SCAN , NO-IBSS

Comment: I am from India. Sorry about the formatting of the terminal output. I am using mobile as internet is not working with the os. That's why

Comment: Try `sudo iw reg set IN` as it might help

Comment: It now displays country as IN for the command $iw reg get but still that shared WiFi network is not appearing in the list.

Comment: Is it broadcasting the SSID, you might be able to check `iwlist scan` to see if there is an access point that has an empty SSID

Comment: We'd love to know about the wireless device and therefore the driver. Please post: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant info in one spot so the next person coming around to try to help you doesn't have to read all the comments. as I just did for you now.

Comment: @Fabby Thank you for guiding me through the best practices. I have updated the question as you suggested.

Comment: @chili555 Please find the question updated with the command outputs you asked for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find out which driver is installed:

```
lsmod | grep -e wl -e brcmsmac
```

This: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) suggests that the correct driver is *brcmsmac*. If you have *wl*, you will have much better performance with the former. Remove the incorrect driver:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and let us hear the result.