# Only some wireless connections detected on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04

I am facing the exact similar problem as mentioned [in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/588843/wifi-network-not-appearing-in-ubuntu-14-04/783786#783786) except that it on Ubuntu 16.04.

I can find some wireless networks available but not the one I want to connect to. I am able to connect to that network using my mobile.

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 0280    
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

I performed an `iw reg set IN` to set it to India.

I installed the right driver `bcmwl-kernel-source` as mentioned in the below link. Only when I installed that driver I was able to find some wireless networks but unfortunately not mine.

Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers

```
$ lsmod | grep -e wl -e brcmsmac    
wl       6365184 0 
cfg80211 565248 1 wl
```

Is there something I am missing? How can I get my wireless connection listed? Please help.

Comment: What channel is your wifi on that Ubuntu can't see?

Comment: @Jeremy31, currently its on channel 12. Signal strength is very good and also no interference from the surroundings.

Comment: Try 11 or lower, I have doubts about that driver.  I think that 11-14 are disabled by the driver

Comment: @Jeremy31,  Modified the channel below 11 and I am able to connect to my wifi. Thank you so much for the help.